# Can't write in inflate layout

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, broadcastreceiver, layout-inflater

I'm using a broadcastreceiver in my DrawerActivity in which i can receive a notification from a service and then i would set the text of notification in a layout that is in a fragment (The first fragment of the navigation drawer). So my DrawerActivity is where i start the broadcastreceiver (i tried start it directly from the fragment but it doesn't work!) So this is the broadcastreceiver:

```
 public BroadcastReceiver onNotice= new BroadcastReceiver() {
        LinearLayout notificationLayout;
        Drawable icon;

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            final String pack = intent.getStringExtra("package");
            String title = intent.getStringExtra("title");
            String text = intent.getStringExtra("text");

            View myView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null);
            notificationLayout = (LinearLayout)myView.findViewById(R.id.notificationLayout);
            TextView notificationDescription = (TextView) myView.findViewById(R.id.notificationDesc);
            TextView notificationTitle = (TextView) myView.findViewById(R.id.notificationTitle);
            CircularImageView notificationImage = (CircularImageView) myView.findViewById(R.id.img_thumbnail);

            Log.i("Notification ", title);
            Toast.makeText(DrawerActivity.this, title, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            if(!pack.equals("") || !title.equals("") || !text.equals("")) {
                notificationLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                notificationTitle.setText("Ciao");
                notificationDescription.setText(text);

                try {
                    icon = DrawerActivity.this.getPackageManager().getApplicationIcon(pack);
                } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                notificationImage.setImageDrawable(icon);

                notificationLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {

                        try {
                            PackageManager pmi = DrawerActivity.this.getPackageManager();
                            Intent intent;

                            intent = pmi.getLaunchIntentForPackage(pack);
                            if (intent != null) {
                                DrawerActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
                            }
                            //LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(MainActivity.instance).sendBroadcast(new Intent("collapseAfterClick"));
                        } catch (Exception ignored) {
                        }
                    }
                });

                notificationLayout.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onLongClick(View view) {

                        notificationLayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);


                        return true;
                    }
                });
            } else {
                notificationLayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }

        }
    };
```

in this way it's very strange!!! When a notification arrives the toast inside the Broadcastrecevier is fired but the settext in the inflate layout not! So i can see the notification from the Toast but not in my layout! How is possible?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the code doesnt enter the if statement.

```
        *if(!pack.equals("") || !title.equals("") || !text.equals(""))*
```

Comment: Yes, but even if i delete that line seems not working..how can i solve?

Comment: Have you got any solution?